# Check if string value is on enumeration c#

Tags: c#, string, enums

```
enum conc
    {
        Maia,
        Porto,
        Valongo,
        Gondomar,
        Gaia,
        Matosinhos
    };



private string concelho;

    public string Concelho
    {
        get { return concelho; }
        set { concelho = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(conc), Concelho) ? value : " "; }
    }
```

Is not working for me, im a student and it is "new" for me. My problem is the verification, what am i do wrong? Thanks

Comment: use `enum.TryParse`.

Comment: You're checking whether the _current_ value of `Concelho` is valid, not the value you're trying to set.

Comment: Also something to keep in mind.  Saying "it doesn't work", is rather vague.  Try to include any error messages, unexpected results, etc., to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Error:AgumentNullException was unhandled

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: What is your reason for doing this? conc is known at compile time so there shouldn't be any surprises. What problem/requirement are you trying to solve with this approach?

Comment: Rather than editing the name of your question with "Resolved" you can accept the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the value directly to the concelho field since it must first be parsed to the enum type.

```
public string Concelho
{
    get { return concelho; }
    set 
    { 
        conc temp;
        if(Enum.TryParse(value, true, out temp))
            cocelho = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: PERFECT!  
     set {
                conc temp;
                if (Enum.TryParse(value, true, out temp))
                    concelho = Convert.ToString(temp);
            }

Thanks a lot, now i need to understand the code.

Comment: I just noticed that your `concelho` variable is of type `string`, you may want to change that to type `conc`. For my answer to work, if you really do want it to be a `string` go with @tinstaafl answer

Answer (score 0):

Your original code is close.  You just need to change `Concelho` to `value`:

```
enum conc
{
    Maia,
    Porto,
    Valongo,
    Gondomar,
    Gaia,
    Matosinhos
};



private string concelho;

public string Concelho
{
    get { return concelho; }
    set { concelho = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(conc), value) ? value : " "; }
}
```

That being said.  You could simply make the type `conc` and call the ToString() method if you need a string representation.

```
public enum conc
{
    Maia,
    Porto,
    Valongo,
    Gondomar,
    Gaia,
    Matosinhos
};



private conc concelho;

public conc Concelho
{
    get { return concelho; }
    set { concelho = value; }
}
```